# Risks when connecting Public WLAN networks

Tags: android, wireless

I want to refer with my question directly to a question posted on the forum before.
[wifi topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46533/are-there-risks-associated-with-connecting-to-a-public-hotspot)

I am running teamviewer on my android which is not rooted and i am not using a firewall on it.
I guess Teamviewer could run such services AJ Henderson is reckoning in his answer that could be tried to get accessed by other computers on the network.

I also guess that if such a service would allow other computers to access them this would be a serious security vulnerability that one might read about in an article in a computer magazine when discovered or am i wrong with this assumption?

Since this question was put on hold i want to add the following sentences.

I don't understand how it would happen that some other PC using the same router is attacking me or a program i am using, could someone please describe what exactly would happen on the attacker side, how the attacker would see which programs i am using that he could try to attack and what roughly would be the next steps the attacker would take.

Also i am asking myself if ufw default deny all incoming is sufficient protection against those kind of attacks.